# Is there a common way to ask a person to put his/her shirt in his/her pants because it looks more polite?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

[image]

**Is there a common way to ask a person to put his/her shirt in his/her pants because it looks more polite?**

Some people say "**to tuck one's shirt in**", for example, "**could you tuck your shirt in to make you look better and more polite?**".

But, I am not sure "**tuck**" is a common word, **do we have a common word for it?**

Comment: In UK, **tuck** is a (if not *the*) common word for it.

Comment: @WeatherVane, what about American version of "tuck"?

Comment: In the US, we also use the word "tuck" for this, and there are no common alternatives.

Comment: I would not use the phrase "more polite" here though. Having an untucked shirt isn't exactly "impolite." You could say, "neater" or "more presentable" or "more formal."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tuck is a perfectly common word.

Practically everyone here in the English speaking world will understand what **tuck your shirt in** means.

Comment: is it ok to say "oh, your shirt is untucked, you've got to tuck it in"?

Comment: @Tom, yup, perfectly fine.